# Put Backup on Old iPhone

Tags: itunes, backup, iphone

Is it possible, using iTunes, to put a backup of a currently active iPhone onto an older iPhone that has no service?

Basically I want to keep all the text conversations on a separate older device.

It's a backup of an iPhone 6 and I want that backup placed on an iPhone 4S.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware if any way to backup an iOS 8 device and restore it to an iPhone 4S that can only run iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The iPhone 4s can support the same versions of iOS as the iPhone 6 (see [supported devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_8#Supported_devices) and Apple's [iOS 8 information](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios8/) - see screenshot below from [here](https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/)) and both will run the forthcoming iOS 9, so it shouldn't be a problem restoring a backup from the latter onto the former.

[image: IOS 8 supported devices]

I've done something similar, restoring an iOS 8.x iPhone 6 Plus backup onto an iPhone 5 and had no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively there are apps that let you download texts off, such as PhoneView by ecamm but I heard they stopped working in one of the most recent updates, so I would check the demo first.

Comment: I think most of those apps stopped working after they uprated the sandboxing in iOS 8.3 I think you need to jailbreak to do any of that stuff now.

Comment: An iPhone 4s can run iOS 8, which is the latest iOS version. Therefore, it would be possible to put an iPhone 6 backup on the older phone.